# Express post request consistently returns undifined or empty object for req.body despite configuring body parsers

Tags: express, postman

[image]Am having issues passing post data with express. I followed all the posts on this site, read docs but i still get undefined for req.body. I have attached the images to help identify[[image: configuratin in app.js post man] where the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got the solution. You need to select the raw data from the option on body of post man and put the exact data you are sending as shown in the image[image: post man's selections]